# Partclone: error when trying to copy partition used-blocks

Tags: partition, virtual-machine, usb-drive, vmware, cloning

[Partclone](http://www.partclone.org/features):

> provides utilities to back up and restore used-blocks of a partition [...]

My environment is a VMware virtual machine bootstrapped with the Arch Linux ISO and with the following mounted storage:

- `sda`, which is a physical USB flash disk,
- `sdb`, which is a virtual disk (VMDK).

Details follows in the figure:

[image: Disk list]

`df` command output shows that only 527 MB are used on `/dev/sdb1`.
I assume the actual used blocks can be copied onto `/dev/sda1`, whose size is 858 MB.

The related Partclone command and output follows:

[image: Partclone]

Can you give some hints on the error shown in the figure above?
Can Partclone actually perform a copy *only* of filesystem used blocks, therefore saving space?
Or is this feature intended only to make  Partclone faster and not to save space?
If the approach suggested here is mistaken, can you suggest the proper way to copy a filesystem used blocks?

*Update.* A typo has been fixed where `/dev/sda1` was misspelled as `/dev/sdba1`

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sdba1`? That looks like a typo to me. Is it possible that this `partclone.fat32` tool has now created a *file* (not a *device*) `/dev/sdba1` that filled up the root filesystem of your VM? Post the output of

```
ls -l /dev/sdba1
```

then we can tell you for sure.

EDIT: you are trying to clone from a 4 GB block device to a 850 MB block device. Are you sure that `partclone.fat32` is able to reduce the filesystem size automatically? Maybe this is your main issue. Try to add another virtual disk, once with the same size as `/dev/sda` and once with the same size as `/dev/sdb` and try to clone on them both. If the first doesn't work, but the second does, then the target device size is too small.

Comment: Right you are, but restarting the machine from the Arch ISO deletes `/dev/sdba1`. Anyway typo was corrected, but problem remains, see new pics.

Comment: What I am testing here is the actual capability of `partclone` to understand filesystems and copy/clone only used blocks, since I am dissatisfied with tools requiring same size devices. In the first screenshot you can see that I mounted `sdb1` and run `df -h /dev/sdb1` exactly to show that the its size is 527M, so it can fit `sda`, which is 858M.

Comment: @antonio But are you certain that it is actually able to *reduce* the filesystem size? "Clone only used sectors" could very well mean that fewer bytes are transferred (by only transferring used sectors), but that the filesystem structure and therefore its size remain unchanged.

Comment: @antonio well, it seems like you've found another tool that requires the same device size. I may be wrong because I've never used `partclone`, but it sure looks to me as if it doesn't support resizing.

Comment: [Quote from what seems to be the `partclone` author, Thomas Tsai: "Partclone just a partition clone tool, not include resize function" (01/2012).](http://sourceforge.net/p/partclone/discussion/638475/thread/f86b2bed/)

Comment: sorry Martin, maybe I am missing something. Anyway I don't mean to resize a partition I just want to copy the used blocks from partition X to Y. If the size of used blocks on X is smaller than the size of Y, I assume cloning can be done despite Y is smaller than (the whole) X partition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10775/discussion-between-martin-von-wittich-and-antonio)

Answer (score 1):

Command is correct except the typo `/dev/sdba1`

> Revise the command and you will get the desired result

Comment: Typo corrected, but problem remains, see new pics.

Comment: Look like, `/dev/sdb1` is out of memory. Try by freeing up `/dev/sdb1/` or increasing it's size

Comment: sorry, don't get it. `/dev/sdb1` is a physical flash pen, created with YUMI. How do I increase its size ?